# Is there software for viewing image pixels easily?

Tags: image-processing, windows

I need software to check the pixel values manually of an image (**Tiff**, jpg, png,...) in an easy way (like specifying the pixel location (x,y) and then the software should give me the values of all the bands related to that pixel i.e. Red, Green, Blue, Temperature, ...).

Preferable to be Windows GUI Software.

Comment: I guess that your request mainly concerns Tiff images, as the other formats only support RGB. So you should rather look for a specialized Tiff reader.

Comment: Actually I am interested in both but more for Tiff bands

Answer (score 0):

You would use Adobe Photoshop image - image size

Comment: Dear I want the values of the pixel not to resize the image. Read the question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

The TIF file you have now provided shows it is actually a pyramid TIFF with 8 sub-images of successively smaller sizes:

```
identify tjpeg.tiff 

tjpeg.tiff[0] TIFF 16716x16716 16716x16716+0+0 8-bit sRGB 152MB 0.010u 0:00.009
tjpeg.tiff[1] TIFF 8358x8358 8358x8358+0+0 8-bit sRGB 152MB 0.000u 0:00.000
tjpeg.tiff[2] TIFF 4179x4179 4179x4179+0+0 8-bit sRGB 152MB 0.000u 0:00.000
tjpeg.tiff[3] TIFF 2090x2090 2090x2090+0+0 8-bit sRGB 152MB 0.000u 0:00.000
tjpeg.tiff[4] TIFF 1045x1045 1045x1045+0+0 8-bit sRGB 152MB 0.000u 0:00.000
tjpeg.tiff[5] TIFF 523x523 523x523+0+0 8-bit sRGB 152MB 0.000u 0:00.000
tjpeg.tiff[6] TIFF 262x262 262x262+0+0 8-bit sRGB 152MB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

If you want a pixel from the top layer (the one with the highest resolution), you will need to select it by appending a zero to the filename:

```
convert -define tiff:ignore-tags=34264,34461,34725,34737 tjpeg.tiff[0] -colorspace rgb -colors 256 -format "%[pixel:p{8000,8000}]" info:

rgb(59,59,44)
```

**Original Answer**

You can use **ImageMagick** at the command line and maybe wrap a GUI around it if you want to. It works with over 160 image file formats from BMP, through TIF, JPEG, GIF.

So, to find the colour of the top-left pixel of a JPEG:

```
convert image.jpg -colorspace rgb -colors 256 -format "%[pixel:p{0,0}]" info:
rgb(7,7,8)
```

To find the colour of pixel 100,100 in a TIF:

```
convert image.tif -colorspace rgb -colors 256 -format "%[pixel:p{100,100}]" info:
rgb(7,7,8)
```

Comment: @YvesDaoust Hello Yves. The new version 7 ImageMagick should handle multi band imagery but I have not checked. If you have a small multispectral TIF lying around that you want to share with me, I will test it for you. My Email domain is `thesetchells.com` and my name is `mark` - sure you will work it out.

Comment: Er, I am not the OP.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, I understand. I thought you had some personal reason to want to know about multi-spectral imagery.

Comment: Dear @Mark Setchell, I followed the URL: https://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php. I downloaded both: "Win32 dynamic at 8 bits-per-pixel component" And "Win32 static at 8 bits-per-pixel component". No one of them contains the executable "convert" you referd to. As a result "convert" I think is detected as a different executable in System32. Also ImageMagic is in the first of the Environment Variables > Path. Could tell me which file to download and where to find the convert executable.

Comment: The newest version uses `magick` in place of `convert` so just use `magick` where I wrote `convert`.

Comment: "magick" is right but I tried it for some files and it shows either errors or doesn't give output. Do you have a better software or a tiff file that can work work on.

Comment: @MosabShaheen I don't understand why you want me to provide a sample image - you must surely have your own images? Anyway, you can make one like this `magick -size 256x256 gradient:red-yellow test.tif`

Comment: @Mark, I said "I tried it for some files and it shows either errors or doesn't give output".
I am interested on the images that I have not the ones created by the "magick". 
see for example: http://download.osgeo.org/geotiff/samples/misc/tjpeg.tif
can you test it and tell me the command to get the pixel values from it.

Comment: @MosabShaheen Please have another look.

Comment: @Mark dear I tried this: "D:\images>magick -define tiff:ignore-tags=34264,34461,34725,34737 tjpeg.tif[0] -colorspace rgb -colors 256 -format "%[pixel:p{8000,8000}]" info:rgb(59,59,44)"

I got:

magick: Unknown field with tag 34735 (0x87af) encountered.
Then I waited 10 minutes and no output. 

By the way I am interested to know what is the meaning of "rgb(59,59,44)"  if it is colour depth it should be either 1,8,16 but here there is 59 and 44?
also what is the meaning of tjpeg.tif[0]    i.e. "0"  is an index for what?

Comment: The `[0]` is the index of the image in the file - see the updated answer where I explained that index 0 is the full size image, index 1 is the half size image and so on - they are all listed with their indices and sizes after the `identify` command example.

Comment: `rgb(0,0,0)` means that the Red, Green and Blue components of the pixel are all zero, i.e. it is a black pixel. A red pixel would be `rgb(255,0,0)`. A green pixel would be `rgb(0,255,0)` and a white pixel would be `rgb(255,255,255)`.

Comment: @Mark thanks for explaining, regarding the rgb(?,?,?) the values here i.e."?" are the ones that I am searching for, so how can I provide them as input in the "convert" command and those are the results i.e. output that I want to get...

Comment: Not sure I understand your question... but if you want to make a red image, you can do `convert -size 256x256 xc:"rgb(255,0,0)" red.png`, if that is what you mean.

Comment: @Mark actually dear my original question is how to get the values of a specific pixel (at a specific location) not how to set them (or giving them a value)

Comment: I am lost now. I thought you wanted to provide the [x,y] location of a pixel and get the RGB values at that position which is what my original answer shows.

Answer (score 0):

Check out **[ImageJ](https://imagej.net/ij/download.html) .**

It's free, and allows you to easily see the raw values of the image, as well as do lots of processing with it

From wikipedia:

> ImageJ can display, edit, analyze, process, save, and print 8-bit
> color and grayscale, 16-bit integer, and 32-bit floating point images.
> It can read many image file formats, including TIFF, PNG, GIF, JPEG,
> BMP, DICOM, and FITS, as well as raw formats. ImageJ supports image
> stacks, a series of images that share a single window, and it is
> multithreaded, so time-consuming operations can be performed in
> parallel on multi-CPU hardware. ImageJ can calculate area and pixel
> value statistics of user-defined selections and intensity-thresholded
> objects. It can measure distances and angles. It can create density
> histograms and line profile plots. It supports standard image
> processing functions such as logical and arithmetical operations
> between images, contrast manipulation, convolution, Fourier analysis,
> sharpening, smoothing, edge detection, and median filtering. It does
> geometric transformations such as scaling, rotation, and flips. The
> program supports any number of images simultaneously, limited only by
> available memory.